# How to extract actionscript classes from a swf file?

Tags: class, actionscript, flash, fla

when I try to extract `.fla` and `.as` from `.swf` (from *Sothink SWF Decompiler*), the classes in the file `.as` are all numbers, like this:

```
aso#33082.onPress = function ()
{
```

or

```
function    ()
{
    for (aso#88375 = 0; aso#88375 < 1000; aso#88375++)
    {
        delete eval("_root.map.arrows.arrow" + aso#88375).onEnterFrame;
    }
```

why there are those numbers?
is there any way to extract the classes correctly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, this information is lost once the SWF is compiled in release mode.